# How to find an OSGi bundle providing a specific capability (JavaEL 5.0)

Tags: java, maven, osgi, bnd

I am using Felix implementation of OSGi.
I have a plugin I wrote which uses `hibernate-validator`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I use the `bnd-process` goal of the `biz.aQute.bnd:bnd-maven-plugin` plugin to package that bundle.
When opening the `MANIFEST.MF` generated, I find the following entry:

```
Require-Capability: osgi.extender;filter:="(&(osgi.extender=osgi.compone
 nt)(version>=1.5.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))",osgi.contract;osgi.contract=Ja
 vaEL;filter:="(&(osgi.contract=JavaEL)(version=5.0.0))",osgi.ee;filter:
 ="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=17))"
```

Notice the `osgi.contract;osgi.contract=JavaEL;filter:="(&(osgi.contract=JavaEL)(version=5.0.0))"` part.
Now if I look at https://docs.osgi.org/reference/portable-java-contracts.html#jakarta-ee-contracts, I only find either `Jakarta Expression Language` in version `5.0` or `JavaEL` in version `3.0`. There is no such `JavaEL` in `5.0` version.

I found the "hard way" that I need to add:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.el</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.el-api</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

to my `pom.xml` *and* `,jakarta.el;version="5.0.0"` to my `Private-Package` `bnd` configuration of the `bnd-maven-plugin`, but I wonder whether there is an easier way.

Now what is annoying me is that my core application has the `Jakarta Expression Language` version `5.0` as its available capability, but not `JavaEL` `5.0`, so I need to declare that dependency in each of my plugins (some of which I do not even control the development flow).

Hence my questions:

- Is this a bug in the capability resolution engine in the
  `bnd-maven-plugin` after the infamous `javax` renaming into
  `jakarta`?
- Is there any way I can avoid my plugins to explicitly
  import `jakarta-el` when my core application has the capability, but
  with a different name?
- Or am I doing something wrong somehow?

Comment: this is tough i can try to replicate it later.

In the meantime can your core application (assuming it's an osgi bundle) use  Provide-Capability ?  

here is a project doing it for "JavaEL 4.0" https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/commit/7928036fd8084f268f5c9451d0cc634f7ce1de35#diff-ee0993bfa902ee1455320e2cdedbed08922f1639d2ee3ab09f660cd3725cf0ddR21

Comment: That seems to be a very good option indeed, but my core application is not an OSGi bundle. I will still try to see if I can push the capability using another dummy package which would only provide the capability, until the issue is "fixed" (assuming there is something to be fixed?). Do you think it could be a good idea as well?

Comment: @SheenaArtrip it seems to do the trick. Thank you very much! Do you think it should be temporary, waiting for either BND to fix the resolution name during `javax` renaming or Felix to provide both `javax` and `jakarta` capabilities?

Comment: I couldn't say, sorry.